# Discord Bot won't run pass certain point in my if statement | Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, split, discord.js

- I can't figure out why my code doesn't run anything past the first
  if statement.
- I can make it run completely if I predefine the time
  variable.
- Although I'm not sure when I try to take the user input,
  it won't continue.
- I don't code much in JavaScript so I'm probably missing something
  obvious. All help is appreciated.

```
if (msg.content === "$set") {
    time = msg.content.split("$set ")[1]
    if(!time)return msg.reply("how many minutes / hours will you set the alarm")
    
    // Nothing runs past here unless I predefine the time variable

    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#26aaff')
    .setTitle('Custom Alert Set')
    .setAuthor('Temp', 'https://i.imgur.com/XX6I7Hj.jpeg', 'https://imgur.com/')
    .setDescription(`Time: ${time}`)
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/XX6I7Hj.jpeg')
    .addFields(
      { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
      { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Built by', 'https://i.imgur.com/XX6I7Hj.jpeg');

    msg.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) command for checking if the `msg.content` starts with `$set`. Then, the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) command should have a valid parameter, so, here you can use a space `" "`.

```
if (msg.content.startsWith("$set")) {
 time = msg.content.split(" ")[1]
if(!time) return msg.reply("how many minutes / hours will you set the alarm");

const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#26aaff')
.setTitle('Custom Alert Set')
.setAuthor('Temp', 'https://i.imgur.com/XX6I7Hj.jpeg', 'https://imgur.com/')
.setDescription(`Time: ${time}`)
.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/XX6I7Hj.jpeg')
.addFields(
  { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
  { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
)
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter('Built by', 'https://i.imgur.com/XX6I7Hj.jpeg');

 msg.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
}
```

Tell me if this works! 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're checking if `msg.content` is **exactly** `"$set"`

I think you want to be checking if `msg.content` *contains* `"$set"`

So try changing `if (msg.content === "$set")` to `if (msg.content.startsWith("$set"))`

Comment: This worked, thank you for the explanation!